# Why bother using `FnMut` if the argument is taken by value?

Tags: closures, rust

Here is an example from [Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/fn/closures/closure_examples/iter_any.html):

```
pub trait Iterator {
    // The type being iterated over.
    type Item;

    // `any` takes `&mut self` meaning the caller may be borrowed
    // and modified, but not consumed.
    fn any<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> bool where
        // `FnMut` meaning any captured variable may at most be
        // modified, not consumed. `Self::Item` states it takes
        // arguments to the closure by value.
        F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool {}
}
```

Why bother using `FnMut` if the argument is taken by value, since the argument cannot be mutated anyways? In fact, why is `FnMut` even allowed here? It seems only `FnOnce` [is permitted to do this](http://rustbyexample.com/fn/closures/input_parameters.html):

> It has been noted that Rust chooses how to capture variables on the
>   fly without annotation. This is all very convenient in normal usage
>   however when writing functions, this ambiguity is not allowed. The
>   closure's complete type, including which capturing type, must be
>   annotated. The manner of capture a closure uses is annotated as one of
>   the following `trait`s:
>
> - `Fn`: takes captures by reference (`&T`)
> - `FnMut`: takes captures by mutable reference (`&mut T`)
> - `FnOnce`: takes captures by value (`T`)

Comment: What do you mean by "the argument is taken by value"? Are you talking about `f: F`?

Comment: Yes. F takes argument by value.

Comment: Could you clarify what you think should be done instead of using `FnMut`?

Comment: Sure, please see my edit.

Answer (score 8):

The distinction between `FnOnce`, `FnMut` and `Fn` is how the function accesses its environment (move, mutable reference, shared reference, respectively). It has nothing to do with accessing the function's arguments.

`FnMut` is needed here, because the `any` method may need to call the function multiple times.

There is a [paragraph in the Rust book about the implementation of closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/closures.html#closure-implementation). It shows the differences in the `self` argument, which essentially is a `struct` that contains the environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Why bother use FnMut if the argument is taken by value, since the arg cannot be mutated anyways?

The example you linked is kind of incorrect, as the method definition should look like this:

```
fn any<F>(&mut self, mut f: F) -> bool  // note the `mut f: F`
    where F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool {}
```

*(compare [the `std` implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f1578d37dc844ffeefcabc30960784082c3c54fa/src/libcore/iter.rs#L1696-L1706))*

This change, however, does not change how the `any` method can be used! The `mut` is merely part of the variable binding (which is only important for the method impl) and not part of the type. Taking something by value gives us complete control over the variable -- if we want to mutate the variable, we can do so, but we have to bind it mutably.

---

> In fact, why is FnMut even allowed here?

You can have trait bounds that *would* allow all kinds of operations with a type, even if you can't use those operations due to lacking access to the variable. See:

```
fn foo<T: Iterator<Item=i32>>(it: &T) {}
```

This is valid, but not useful, because as soon as you want to do something usable with the iterator (like calling `next`):

```
it.next();
```

You will get a compiler error, since you can't call a `&mut self` method on an immutable borrow. So the example you linked only works, because the function body doesn't use the functionality of `FnMut`.

Comment: Why couldn't `any` be defined to take a `Fn` closure?

Comment: @ruohola Oof, what an old and not so great answer by me. Regarding your question: because `FnMut` allows the user to do more things (i.e. mutate its environment). While it's usually not required and doesn't make a lot of sense, we can still give this power to the user of `any`, because why not?